# Been awhile since using Python.. things changed? Script Syntax Error

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x, ssh, nohup

trying to run a `nohup python ~/file.py`, after executing `nohup.out` shows the following error..... and yes this is an instagram autolike script I am messing with.

```
File "/root/likebot.py", line 14
hashtags = ['etsy', 'iOS', 'android', 'website'. 'webdesign', 'webdevelopment', 'graphic', 'smallbusiness', 'business', 'design', 'ineedawebsite', 'oregon', 'washington', 'idaho', 'oklahoma', 'life', 'usa', 'entrepreneur', 'responsive']
                                                           ^SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is invalid here?

Comment: As a side note, if you _seriously_ suspect that something has changed in Python since your last-used version that makes formerly-valid code no longer valid, you'd really need to tell us which version you're using now and which version you used to use. (_Most_ of the dramatic changes happened between 2.x and 3.x, but there is code that was valid 2.5 code and an error in 2.6, etc. as well.)

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo after `'website'.`

This should be a comma.

Answer (score 2):

There's a dot `.` instead of a comma `,` after 'website'.

Answer (score 0):

```
['etsy', 'iOS', 'android', 'website'. 'webdesign', 'webdevelopment', 'graphic', 'smallbusiness', 'business', 'design', 'ineedawebsite', 'oregon', 'washington', 'idaho', 'oklahoma', 'life', 'usa', 'entrepreneur', 'responsive']
```

There's a `.` instead of a `,`. `------------^`